# How to maximize a window?

Tags: r, tk-toolkit

I have found a way to [query whether a tk window is maximized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428368/tcl-tk-maximize-window-determine-if-window-is-maximized):

```
library(tcltk)
w <- tktoplevel()
tkwm.state(w)  # Query the current state; returns "normal" if not maximized
#  The possible states for a window include "normal"m "iconic" (for an iconified window), "withdrawn", "icon" or "zoomed".
# For more details about window states see: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html
```

How can I maximize a `tk` window?

This code does not work (using Ubuntu 14.04):

```
tkwm.state(w, "zoomed")
```

> Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTclObjv, objv), class = "tclObj") :
>   [tcl] bad argument "zoomed": must be normal, iconic, or withdrawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, you must use `wm attributes` to check the zoomed state.  The maximization code is closely tied to the internal system calls and is not cross platform compatible.

```
set iszoomed [wm attributes $w -zoomed]
wm attributes $w -zoomed 1 ; # set to maximized
```

Sorry, don't know the R code for that.

Comment: Great, it works, THX! In R: `tcl("wm", "attributes", my.window, zoomed=TRUE)` maximizes this window (but the menu icons and top bar of Ubuntu Unity are still visible which is normal behaviour).